# Remove Heroku setting from Hubot?

Tags: heroku, hubot

I tried running Hubot on Heroku, but I gave up because I'd prefer not to give out my credit card number.

Instead, I tried running Hubot on my mac. It gave an error, like this:

```
$ ./bin/hubot
hubot-sample> [Fri Jun 05 2015 11:41:52 GMT+0900 (JST)] ERROR hubot-heroku-alive included, but missing HUBOT_HEROKU_KEEPALIVE_URL. `heroku config:set HUBOT_HEROKU_KEEPALIVE_URL=$(heroku apps:info -s  | grep web_url | cut -d= -f2)`
[Fri Jun 05 2015 11:41:52 GMT+0900 (JST)] INFO Using default redis on localhost:6379
```

I think this error occured because Hubot is looking for Heroku. How do I remove this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this.

```
cd <your-hubot-project-dir>
npm uninstall hubot-heroku-keepalive --save
```

Then find and remove the line that contains "hubot-heroku-keepalive" from file "external-scripts.json".

Run "bin/hubot" again.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for late reply. Your post was helped me.

Comment: Also have to remove hubot-heroku-keepalive from the external-scripts.json, or you'll still get a module not found error while loading external scripts.